# How to modify/add a new objectClass to an entry in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I recently setup centralized authentication system using OpenLDAP. Now I need to extend the users that are defined in the database to include a new object class that contains some security related data about them.
How can I modify the existing entries to add this new object class?
I'm pretty new to LDAP so don't bite my head off if I managed to ask a stupid question :P Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `ldapmodify` to modify one or more entries, you just need to feed to the program the credentials and a file containing all the changes you want to do

As an example (taken straight from openldap manual), if your file contains this it'll add/modify all those fields

```
dn: uid=john.doe,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: john.doe
givenName: John
sn: Doe
cn: John Doe
mail: john.doe@example.com
userPassword: password
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm, after I figured out how to defined the adding operation, of course (it differs for adding an attribute). It goes like this (perhaps somebody has a use for it also):  

    dn: uid=john.doe,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
    changetype: add
    add: objectClass
    objectClass: person  

    -- snip --

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example LDIF file to add the objectClass *posixAccount* to an existing entry `uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` of e.g. objectClass *inetOrgPerson*:

```
dn: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: objectClass
objectClass: posixAccount
-
add: homeDirectory
homeDirectory: /home/testuser
-
add: uidNumber
uidNumber: 1000
-
add: gidNumber
gidNumber: 1000
```

The `-` are important to separate the *add* blocks. One has to make sure that all necessary attributes (for *posixAccount* `homeDirectory`, `uidNumber`, `gidNumber`) are added in the same file.

The LDIF file can be added e.g. with

```
ldapmodify -x -D 'cn=root,dc=example,dc=com' -W -f filename.ldif
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenLdap Schema and ObjectClass are easy to extend.
Look inside bundled schema if there is the object of your needs (located, on a debian filesystem is /etc/ldap/schema)

After you can modify your ldap entities and attached to them new objectClass (and, by extension, new attribute types).

If you want to build your own attribute type and/or your own objectClass you need to request an OID object number ([OID Registration](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page)).

Then follow this schema :

```
objectIdentifier YOUR_OID <IANA NUMBER>
objectIdentifier YOUR_OBJECTCLASS YOUR_OID:1
objectIdentifier YOUR_ATTRIBUTETYPE YOUR_OID:2
```

Then define your attribute type:

```
attributetype( YOUR_ATTRIBUTETYPE:1 NAME "your attribute name"
    DESC "quick description"
    EQUALITY typoofequality
    SYNTAX valid syntax
```

And your object class:

```
objectclass(YOUR_OBJECTCLASSS:1 NAME "your objectclass name"
    DESC "quick description"
    SUP top #or another objectclass inheritence
    MUST (list of must attributes, separated by "$")
    MAY (list of may attributes, separated by "$") )
```

The number following the YOUR_ATTRIBUTETYPE/YOUR_OBJECTCLASS must be unique (ie : one number for each attribute)

For reference, have a look at [Open LDAP Schema Specification](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/schema.html)

Comment: The issue was that I didn't know how to attach/add a new objectClass to an already existing entry/entries.